# How to find $E(\tau)$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

**Question.** Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variable with $P(X_i=0)=P(X_i=1)=1/2$. Let $\tau$ be the waiting time until the appearance of the six consecutive $1's$. That is
$$
\tau = \inf\{k \geq 6 : X_{k-5}=1,X_{k-4}=1,..,X_{k}=1\}
$$
Find $E(\tau)$.

**My attempt**:

I am thinking to apply Optional Stopping theorem to find $E(\tau)$.

Firstly, I have shown that $P(\tau < \infty)=1$. Let
$$
Y_i = 2^61_{\{X_i=1,X_{i+1}=1,..X_{i+5}=1\}}
$$
Then I define a random variable $$
Z_n= \sum_{i =1}^n E[Y_i|F_n]-n
$$
I proved the $Z_n$ is a martingale w.r.t to $F_n$ where $F_n= \sigma(X_1,....X_n)$.

If I will show that $\tau$ is a stopping time, then
by Optional Stopping theorem ,

$$E(Z_{\tau})=E(Z_1)$$.

I got $E(Z_1)=0$, this implies $$ E(\tau)= \sum_{i=1}^\tau E(E(Y_i|F_{\tau})$$

I am not sure how to conclude the last part of this question, can anyone help me with this?

Can anyone also suggest how do I claim $\{\tau \leq n\}\in F_n$ to prove $\tau$ is a stopping time?

Comment: Since $\tau \ge 6$ it is clear that for $n\le 5$ the set $\{\tau\le n\}$ is the empty set and thus in ${\cal F}_n$. For $n\ge 6$ you will know if $\{\tau\le n\}$ once you have observed the first $n$ of he $X_i$. Therefore, $\{\tau\le n\}\in{\cal F}_n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a supplement to @Snoop's answer, which uses the standard Markov chain formulation of this problem.

For us to apply OST, we introduce a casino as follows. At every time $t$, a new player arrives and bets $\$1$ on a fair coin-flip landing on heads (i.e. $X_t = 1$). If the coin lands heads, then the casino pays this player $\$2$ and the player stays at the casino; if the coin lands tails (i.e. $X_t = 0$), the player loses all their money and leaves the casino. At any time $t$, all other remaining players in the casino bet their entire fortune on heads; if the coin lands heads the player doubles their fortune, otherwise they lose it all and leave.

Let $V_t$ be the value process of this casino. By construction, $V_0 = 0$ and since the payoffs are fair, $V_t$ is a martingale. At the stopping time$^\dagger$ $\tau$, the casino will have received an inflow of $\tau$ dollars and will have paid off the wagers each of the players who entered the casino at times $\tau - 5, \tau - 4, \ldots , \tau - 1, \tau$.
By the construction of the betting strategy, the outflow of this casino is $2+4+8+16+32+64$. Altogether, the value process of this casino at $\tau$ amounts to $$V_\tau = \tau - (2+4+8+16+32+64) = \tau - 126$$
By the OST$^{\dagger \dagger}$, we get: $$0 = E(V_0) = E(V_\tau ) = E(\tau) -126$$
So that $E(\tau) = 126 = 2(2^{6}-1)$, which agrees with @Snoop's answer.

---

A couple of technical remarks are remaining:

$(\dagger)$ Observe that for a discrete-time process, $\{\tau \leq k\}\in \mathcal{F}_k$ for all $k$ is equivalent to $\{\tau = k\} \in\mathcal{F}_k$ for all $k$. Note that $\{\tau_k = k\} = \{X_{k-5}=1,X_{k-4}=1, \ldots = X_k = 1\} \in \mathcal{F}_k = \sigma(X_1, \ldots , X_k)$, as the truthiness of $\{X_{k-5}=1,X_{k-4}=1, \ldots = X_k = 1\}$ can be determined by the states of $X_t$ up to time $k$.

$(\dagger \dagger)$ To apply the OST, we can show that $E(\tau) <\infty$ by using an argument analogous to the one used to show that gambler's ruin has a stopping time with bounded first moment. In particular, one sees that $\tau$ is stochastically dominated by $6Y$ where $Y \sim Geo(2^{-6})$, so that $E(\tau) \leq 6E(Y) <\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I understood your way to find $E(\tau)$. Is there any suggestion to solve this problem where I left my attempt i.e, $E(\tau) = \sum_{i=1}^\tau E(E(Y_i|F_{\tau}))$?

Comment: @Snoop Woops! Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @JoseAvilez love this answer, I like the casino setting

Comment: @User124356 You can compute the expectations on the right-hand explicitly by noting that if $i<\tau - 5$, then $E(Y_i | F_\tau) = E(Y_i) = 0$ by independence. The remaining expectations evaluate, via conditioning, to $2^1, 2^2, \ldots, 2^6$. Note that your approach is equivalent to mine, just expressed in a different language.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I got your point and thanks for explaining this with casino setting.

Answer (score 1):

We use the Markov chain $P(S_{n+1}=j+1|S_n=j)=P(S_{n+1}=0|S_n=j)=1/2,\,0\leq j<k$ and $P(S_{n+1}=S_n|S_n=k)=1$ where $S$ is the number of consecutive successes (state space $\mathcal{S}=\{0,1,...,k\}$) and $k$ the absorbing state. Note that
$$E[\tau|S_0=j]=E[\tau|S_1=j+1]\frac{1}{2}+E[\tau|S_1=0]\frac{1}{2}=1+E[\tau|S_0=j+1]\frac{1}{2}+E[\tau|S_0=0]\frac{1}{2}$$
$$E[\tau|S_0=k]=0$$
We get the recursion
$$E_{j}=1+\frac{1}{2}E_{j+1}+\frac{1}{2}E_0,\,0\leq j<k$$
$$E_k=0$$
where $E_k$ is the mean hitting time of the absorbing state starting from state $k$. We solve for $E_0$ obtaining
$$E_0=2(2^k-1)$$

Comment: Could you please give me the direction to solve this problem by using Optional Stopping Theorem?

Comment: @User124356 I tried using OST but I could not get around some issues that arose either with the adaptability of the martingale or with $\tau$ being a stopping time

Comment: @Snoop Nice answer +1! I think the OP is looking for a "casino style" argument, which is the classic way of solving the so-called ABRACADABRA problem. See [Martingales and the ABRACADABRA Problem](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Ai.pdf) for a discussion of this proof strategy.

Comment: @JoseAvilez thanks!! Also for the reference